# Python how to search files using regular expression

Tags: python-3.x, regex, glob, subdirectory

I have given a regular expression that has a string that points to the files
all I have is the root path
for example :
I have the root path c:/myapp:

```
c:/myapp/textfiles/file0.txt
c:/myapp/textfiles/b1/b2/file1.txt
c:/myapp/textfiles/b1/c2/b2/file2.txt
```

The regular expressions are :
**A.**

```
'textfiles/file0.txt'
```

and
**B.**

```
textfiles\/b1\/b2\/file.*txt|textfiles\/b1\/c2\/b2\/\/file.*txt
```

how can i use python glob or regexp find the files using A and B regexp

Comment: Perhaps like `^c:/myapp/textfiles/(?:.*/)?file\d+\.txt$` https://regex101.com/r/RAOVyE/1

Comment: As an aside, there is no reason to backslash the slashes.